# Decreasing font size and space in verbatimInput{data.txt}

Tags: fontsize, verbatim

How to decrease the text size and reduce space in VerbatimInput{data.txt}. Also text goes out of page both horizontally and vertically.[image]

```
\begin{figure}


        \fbox{\begin{minipage}{16.7em} \VerbatimInput{RoleUser.txt} 
\end{minipage}}

    \caption{The result of the analysis using OFMC and CL-AtSe backend of our scheme}

    \label{fig:The result of the analysis using OFMC and CL-AtSe backend of our scheme}

\end{figure}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
\VerbatimInput[fontsize=\footnotesize]{...}
```

There is a documentation, run: `texdoc fancyvrb`.
Do *not* use a minipage if you want to allow page breaks!